# StackExchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™ colour issue

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, top-bar

Opening up the StackExchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™ after the recolouring on Ask Ubuntu main and hovering over the Stack Exchange logo results in dark grey on purple:

[image]

This is somewhat unreadable and really doesn't look very good. Can we keep it as a white "Stack" or change the colour of the background when the SuperDropdown™ is... dropped... down?

Comment: Yep, same here... Only in the main site, tho.

Comment: Also, only when you have the pointer hovering the thingy

Comment: Yeah. On meta there's a `.topbar .topbar-icon-on, .topbar .topbar-icon-on:hover` rule that covers the "on" states in both standard and `:hover`, so the colour is the same. The main site has differing rules for `:hover`. I prefer the meta way.

Comment: Arqade works (visually) the same way as AU meta, not that I've checked what is actually going on.

Comment: Well thats... Pretty. Looks nice.

Comment: @thomas that is already stated in the question. It's still an issue and it still needs fixing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've put in a fix for this. It will go out with our next prod build.